# keras conv1d layer custom padding

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, keras-layer

I would like to customize the padding value of a conv1d layer, however the only values accepted seem to be 'same' and 'valid', In PyTorch it is instead possible to specify the desired padding value.
Is there a workaround to achieve that with Tensorflow?

Comment: So you need something other than zero as the padded value?

Comment: Yes, I'd like to customize the padding to a value other than zero. With 'same' padding it automatically makes the padding, for what is mine understanding, while with 'valid' it makes zero padding.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you don't want to change the value used for padding, but the number of values padded before and after the input tensor. For this, you should use one of the ZeroPadding layers, which exist in 1D, 2D, and 3D variants, for example, the ZeroPadding1D layer [1](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r2.10/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/ZeroPadding1D). So this means you need two layers instead of 1, the first does the padding and the second does the convolution. In case you want to change the padding value you would need to use the Tensorflow tf.pad function, that you could encapsulate into a custom layer:

```
class TFPadLayer(keras.layers.Layer):
    """Padding layer. access to tf.pad function
    """

    def __init__(self, paddings, padding_type="REFLECT", name="PadLayer", 
                 constant_value=0.,    
                 **kwargs):
        super().__init__(name=name, **kwargs)
        # convert padding_size into 1D array
        self.paddings = paddings
        self.padding_type = padding_type.upper()
        self.constant_value = constant_value

    def call(self, inputs):

        return tf.pad(inputs,
                          paddings=self.paddings,
                          mode=self.padding_type,
                          constant_values=tf.cast(self.constant_value, inputs.dtype))

print(TFPadLayer([[0,0], [1, 2], [0,0]], padding_type="CONSTANT", constant_value=1.)(tf.zeros((1, 3, 1))))
print(TFPadLayer([[0,0], [1, 2], [0,0]], padding_type="REFLECT")(tf.range(4, dtype=tf.float32)[tf.newaxis, :, tf.newaxis]))
```

results in

```
tf.Tensor(
[[[1.]
  [0.]
  [0.]
  [0.]
  [1.]
  [1.]]], shape=(1, 6, 1), dtype=float32)
tf.Tensor(
[[[1.]
  [0.]
  [1.]
  [2.]
  [3.]
  [2.]
  [1.]]], shape=(1, 7, 1), dtype=float32)
```